# Count the total number of non-unique items in a list

Tags: python, list, optimization, duplicates

I am looking for the most time-efficient way to calculate the number of non-unique items in a large list (around 100,000 items) for Python.

The method I have so far:

```
original_list = [1, 4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2]

duplicates_list = []
for item in original_list:
    if original_list.count(item) > 1:
        duplicates_list.append(item)

duplicates_count = len(duplicates_list)

print(duplicates_count)

# Should give the following answer:
5
```

Currently, a large list of around 70-80K items takes 1-2 mins to perform the calculation. I am wondering if we can reduce the time needed for the calculation as low as possible (maybe to 3-10 seconds).

I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: `len(original_list) - len(set(original_list))` @TimeAndPlaces

Comment: @Todd I need to count all copies of items that have duplicates. I believe your solution will also remove 1 copy of each item that has a duplicate.

Comment: @Todd this doesn't work.  It counts the amount of excess, not the population of that set.

Comment: That's true, it will only count the number of duplicates without including the original item in the count.

Comment: @Todd Couldn't you do `+ 1`?

Comment: hmm.. that'd be 4, but he says there's 5

Comment: @Todd Yes, total items with duplicates would be `1, 1, 2, 2, 2`

Comment: @Todd I think it will work if I will modify your example like this: `len(original_list - set(original_list)) + len(set(original_list - set(original_list))`

Comment: interesting.. i'll test that out.. eh.. not sure what you're attempting. can't subtract a list from a set.

Comment: @Todd I know, just wanted to show a simplified version of what you can do. I think an answer given by David down below is still a more elegant solution. But thank you for chiming in!

Comment: `len(orig) - len(set(orig)) + len(set(<< orig - set(orig) >>))` - but I don't know how to get the difference set.

Comment: The bot is offline.
I know you'll see this and have already realized long ago.
@TimesAndPlaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Counter object should be faster as, in your version, you're calling `count()` on every item in the list, so 100,000 times per your question. This will perform the Count() once on the whole list, then iterating over the Counter object will only be once per unique value.

```
original_list = [1, 4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2]

from collections import Counter
count = Counter(original_list)

dupes = sum(v for k, v in count.items() if v > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This takes advantage of support for arithmetic operators in the `Counter` class - both `set` and `Counter` support several useful operations:

```
>>> li = [1, 4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2]
>>> s  = set(li)
>>>
>>> len(li) - len(s) + len(Counter(li) - Counter(s))
5
>>>
```

`len(li) - len(set(li))` gives the number of duplicates, or the number of list items left after we take out the `set` items.

To get a list of set items that are related to an item in the leftover list:

```
>>> list((Counter(li) - Counter(set(li))))
[1, 2]
```

And to get the list of duplicates left over in the list after the `set` items are all removed:

```
>>> list((Counter(li) - Counter(set(li))).elements())
[1, 2, 2]
```

If there were a subtract operation for lists, that's what we'd get after subtracting the `set` from the list.

**Suggested optimization**

*If possible, the application that uses this list of 70-80K items should incrementally build up the Counter from the start as it populates the list. It could have its list, Counter, or other needed structures on hand when needed, so metrics or other types of processing can be shortcut in later steps.*

**Benchmarks**

In no particular order, here's how long it took each algorithm to process a list of 80K random numbers.

```
>>> li     = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(80 * 1000)]
>>> n_iter = 1000
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit("s = set(li); "
...               "len(li) - len(s) + len(Counter(li) - Counter(s))", 
...               globals=globals(), number=n_iter)
7.048838693
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(v for k, v in Counter(li).items() if v > 1)", 
...               globals=globals(), number=n_iter)
5.787936814
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit(original_posters_script, globals=globals(), number=n_iter)
# Takes too much time to sit through. It's very slow. O(N^2)
>>>
```

Not surprisingly, the fastest algorithm is the other Counter solution in the selected Answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! How would I define the number of duplicates + items that have duplicates, then? Just looking for a word to lesser the confusion

Comment: Okay, I got it. Maybe this works: "I want the number of unique non-duplicated items." There's a nuance of difference between "non-duplicated item" vs "non-duplicate item".

Comment: Awesome @TimesAndPlaces